# How to get the values of a circle of pixels on an image?

Tags: matlab

I'm currently using MatLab as part of a Digital Imaging course and trying to get the values of a circle of pixels on an image. The idea is to start with a central pixel (*x, y*) and then collect all of the pixels with the radius *r* and return their values.

So far, all I've managed to create is this (where `A_grey` is an image):

```
function [localMean] = getLocalMean(x, y, radius)
for x = 1:size(A_grey, 1)
    for y = 1:size(A_grey, 2)
       <code> 
    end
end
```

But I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing and I could really do with some beginner level advice here. Any tips?

Comment: It's your course, so you should do it. My advice is spacing the angle equal and use that points on a circle can be computed by radius and angle.

Comment: Or polar coordinates....

Comment: I've been trying to do this for a while, but the teaching has been terrible and I really don't know how to complete this. I know it's my course, but I just need a few pointers in the right direction.

Comment: Set a centre point, set a radius, Look into how to convert polar coordinates into Cartesian (x,y).I'm not able to show you at the moment but it should be straight forward.

Comment: Your function declaration and what you are trying to compute don't correspond to each other.  Assuming what you talked about in your question is what you are after, I've written my answer.

Comment: Do you require any more assistance?

Comment: Well, I was wondering whether there was a way of doing this without the use of a `meshgrid`?

Comment: @Zetland - You can use a loop, but I highly discourage it because doing it through `meshgrid` is more efficient.  If this is what you want, please let me know.  BTW, I didn't get your message because you didn't use the @ tag.  If you need to send me a message that.

Comment: @Zetland - Why do you not want to use `meshgrid`? Why don't you tell us what you're really after. [#xyproblemwoot](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll throw you a bone.  This is actually quite easy.  Given the size of the image / viewing window, stored in `width` and `height` that you want to examine, generate a [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) of points, then search for those `(x,y)` values that satisfy the equation of the circle.  In other words, you want to search for all `(x,y)` values given a centre of your circle `(x0,y0)` such that:

```
(x - x0)^2 + (y - y0)^2 = r^2
```

`r` is the radius of your desired circle.  As such, it's as simple as:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:width, 1:height);
p = (x - x0).^2 + (y - y0).^2 == r^2;
pts = [x(p) y(p)];
```

We first generate a `meshgrid` of points.  Think of a `meshgrid` as a set of 2D arrays where each unique spatial location in the same spot of these arrays gives you the **x** and **y** coordinates at that spatial location in 2D.  Take a look at the following example:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:3, 1:3)

x =

     1     2     3
     1     2     3
     1     2     3


y =

     1     1     1
     2     2     2
     3     3     3
```

In terms of pixel coordinates, the top-left corner is `(x,y) = (1,1)`.  The top right corner is `(x,y) = (3,1)` and so on.  Note that the convention is that `x` is **horizontal** while `y` is **vertical**, as what most digital image processing literature will give you.  If this is not what you want, replace `meshgrid` with [`ndgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ndgrid.html) to respect the row/column convention.

Once we generate this grid of points, we simply put this through our circle equation and see which values of `(x,y)` at a given centre `(x0,y0)` satisfy the equation of the circle.  Once we find such locations, we simply index into our `meshgrid` of points and return those `(x,y)` values, corresponding to those points that lie along the perimeter of your circle.